# Is it possible to alternate between the two colors in the Brick Node without any in-between shades?

Tags: materials, node-editor

How can I use the Brick node to generate only bricks of color A or B without any in-between shades, and alternate between the two, right-to-left and top-to-bottom.

[image: Desired brick pattern]

I assume it requires manipulation of the Bias value in some way or other, but I haven't been able to figure out what to use where it will have the desired effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than connecting the brick texture to the colour input of your shader, you can use it to define the mix factor of different colours. With this approach you can use a colour ramp node to adjust the shading of the brick texture so you get less variation in the colour.

By connecting the fac of the brick node into a colour ramp you easily get a choice between brick and mortar (assuming you have a mortar size)

Then connect the colour output to a colour ramp that is set to constant interpolation and adjust the positions until you get a variation you are happy with.

Connecting the black and white colour from the colour ramps into the fac of the mix nodes lets you choose which colour is used.

[image]

Which leaves you with two brick colours and a mortar colour.

[image]

Comment: Tha is for your reply! That’s part of the way there and takes care of the A-or-B-only part, but not the alternating, unfortunately. That’s my fault for not explaining it more fully. By "alternating", I mean even bricks would be red, odd bricks would be brown, counting from left to right, top to bottom. I'll update my post above to better reflect what I’m going for.

Comment: *Thanks, not "tha is". Stupid auto-correct...

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I am also wondering if you could add a 3rd solid colored brick

Comment: @NickSieben yes add more stops to the colour ramp after the brick texture. Ask as a question to get more info.